# Using AVFoundation without audio or video

Tags: swift, avfoundation

This may be a stupid question, but I have been digging for days and haven't been able to find a distinct answer.

I would like to know if it is possible to use the AVFoundation framework to synchronize time-based data WITHOUT an audio or video media file.

I am building an application where I need to precisely trigger events on a synchronized timeline. Sometimes these events must be synchronized with an audio or video file, but not always. I would love to be able to use AVFoundation for this as, at least conceptually, it seems to contain everything I need. An AVMutableComposition made up of tracks of recorded values at times that I could play back and use to trigger events (the same way a subtitle would be precisely displayed over a video) would be perfect.

In my investigations of the framework documentation, there are plenty of references that say an AVAsset can be made up of tracks "each of a uniform media type, including but not limited to audio, video, text, closed captions, and subtitles", and a track consisting of text data would probably work for me, but every single actual code example I can find seems to insist an AVAsset has to be tied to an audio or video file on the disk, and Apple's list of supported file formats consists only of video and audio file types.

I completely understand why, and can certainly accept that it may have been built with the requirement of an AV file, but I keep getting drawn back by the cryptic possibility that it just might solve a lot of my problems without having to reinvent the wheel.

So for my question to be answered, I think I need one of two things. Either a definitive answer that I will NOT be able to use AVFoundation for my needs, or some kind of pointer in the right direction of what kind of compatible file type I could use to store non-AV data to use in an AVMutableComposition.

Thanks in advance!